# how can i return the count from a function

Tags: javascript

hi iam new to javascript, i am trying to return a count from the function my code is like below

### my code

```
function moredbCount(contentMoreArray2, ArrHeading) { 
  var sampleArr = [];
  for (var a = 0; a < contentMoreArray2.length; a++) {
    if (ArrHeading !== 'More') {
      var fullHeading = ArrHeading + '-' + contentMoreArray2[a].name;
    } else {
      fullHeading = contentMoreArray2[a].name;
    }
    sampleArr.push(fullHeading);    
  }
  var sampleCount = sampleHeadingCount(sampleArr);
  return sampleCount.then(function (resultantCount) {
    return resultantCount;  //Here iam getting some count like 10 and returning it to the function;  
  });
}
var contentCount; 
 var totalCount = moredbCount(contentMoreArray2, ArrHeading);
 totalCount.then(function (resultantTotalCount) {      
      return contentCount = resultantTotalCount
    });
// Here i want to use contentCount 10, But iam getting undefined
```

Thanks In advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return contentCount = resultantTotalCount` won't return the count, but rather the response of assignment. In `contentCount = resultantTotalCount`, you are basically assigning the value of resultantTotalCount to contentCount.

You should use

```
function moredbCount(contentMoreArray2, ArrHeading) { 
  var sampleArr = [];
  for (var a = 0; a < contentMoreArray2.length; a++) {
    if (ArrHeading !== 'More') {
      var fullHeading = ArrHeading + '-' + contentMoreArray2[a].name;
    } else {
      fullHeading = contentMoreArray2[a].name;
    }
    sampleArr.push(fullHeading);    
  }
  var sampleCount = sampleHeadingCount(sampleArr);
  return sampleCount.then(function (resultantCount) {
    return resultantCount;  //Here iam getting some count like 10 and     returning it to the function;  
  });
}
var contentCount; 
 var totalCount = moredbCount(contentMoreArray2, ArrHeading);
 totalCount.then(function (resultantTotalCount) {      
      return resultantTotalCount
});
```